# I want to show a listview by using multiple string array using xml resources file.I am unable to show it in the listview. I am new in android

Tags: android, listview

This is my datamodel class

> Datamodel.Java

```
public class Datamodel {
private String name;
private String Age;
private String DOB;

public Datamodel(String name, String age, String DOB) {
    this.name = name;



    Age = age;
    this.DOB = DOB;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return Age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    Age = age;
}

public String getDOB() {
    return DOB;
}

public void setDOB(String DOB) {
    this.DOB = DOB;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.example.bengal.testarray.Datamodel{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", Age=" + Age +
            ", DOB='" + DOB + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

This is my ListArrayAdapter class which extends the BaseAdapter

> ListArrayAdapter.java

```
public class ListArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<Datamodel> Details;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public ListArrayAdapter(ArrayList<Datamodel> details, Context context, LayoutInflater layoutInflater) {
    Details = details;
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Details.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return Details.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.details_list, parent, false);
        holder.name =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameID);
        holder.age =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ageID);
        holder.dob=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dobID);
        //holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);


        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Datamodel listdata = (Datamodel) getItem(position);
    holder.name.setText(listdata.getName());
    holder.name.setText(listdata.getAge());
    holder.name.setText(listdata.getDOB());
   //listdata.getName();
   // listdata.getAge();
    //listdata.getDOB();
    //ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(pics.get(position).getImage(), holder.imageView, options);

    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder{
    TextView name;
    TextView age;
    TextView dob;

}
```

}

This is my MainActivity and here I am not being able to add the arrays to the datamodel object. I am stuck here.

> MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
ListArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    String[] arrayName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
    String[] arrayAge = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Ages);
    String[] arrayDOB = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DOBs);

    ArrayList<Datamodel> dm = new ArrayList<Datamodel>();
    dm.toArray(arrayName);
    dm.toArray(arrayAge);
    dm.toArray(arrayDOB);
    adapter = new ListArrayAdapter(dm,this,getLayoutInflater());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            //ArrayList<Datamodel> dtm = new ArrayList<Datamodel>();
            //Collections.addAll(dtm,arrayName);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Below I am providing my xml codes for the mainActivity and for the preview within the list which is details_list.xml

> activity_main.xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" /></RelativeLayout>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/nameID"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:layout_weight="0.80" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:background="#FFAA66CC"
        android:layout_below="@id/nameID"
        android:id="@+id/ageID"
         />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:background="#FF99CC00"
        android:id="@+id/dobID"
        android:layout_below="@id/ageID"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my resources file where I have created three string array and I want to display them in my listview.

> strings.xml

```html
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TestArray</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string-array name="names">
        <item>arman</item>
        <item>adib</item>
        <item>raffique</item>
        <item>ameen</item>
        <item>rajit</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="Ages">
        <item>23</item>
        <item>24</item>
        <item>25</item>
        <item>27</item>
        <item>30</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="DOBs">
        <item>15 January</item>
        <item>17 January</item>
        <item>15 February</item>
        <item>17 February</item>
        <item>19 March</item>
    </string-array>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all for static data, put the values in the string.xml file in values folder under the res directory.The data will look like this
`<string-array name="titles">
        <item>Name</item>
        <item>Date of birth</item>
        <item>Age</item>
        <item>City</item>
     </string-array>`

Then access it in your activity or java file using this code
   Add the following class to your package`public class SingleRow implements Parcelable{

```
String title;

int Age;

SingleRow(String title, int Age){

    this.title =title;
    this.Age= Age;
}

public SingleRow(Parcel in ) {
   this.title=in.readString();

    this.Age=in.readInt();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(title);

    dest.writeInt(Age);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public SingleRow createFromParcel(Parcel in ) {
        return new SingleRow( in );
    }

    public SingleRow[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SingleRow[size];
    }
};`

String [] titles = resources.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
String [] Ages = resources.getStringArray(R.array.ages);
Now in your adapter add this String titles.
```

Comment: using a for loop you can create the object of whole array